# Thumbnail generation with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: 7, media

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for a Drupal 7 site running on Apache2.

When I try to view a thumbnail I get the Drupal 404 page saying that the location is not found.

I have implemented the location rules to rewrite requests to the thumbnail to index.php and the error message includes this rewritten request.

These are my nginx location blocks:

```
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

# Try to serve files with Nginx if possible
location / {
     try_files $uri @proxy;
}

# Pass on php to Apache
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

The url of a thumbnail looks like this:

```
http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-1-1437996028.jpg?itok=19uLP_Ax
```

The error message displayed is:

```
The requested page "/index.php?q=sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-1-1437996028.jpg&itok=19uLP_Ax" could not be found.
```

I have tried setting the flag to allow insecure content generation (without a token) to test with.  Obviously I've removed that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is similar to me, i added this line in my nginx vhost config,

```
location ~* /sites/default/files/styles/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
    break;
    }
}
```

you need to reload to make the image display, hope someone can improve my answer